# How to merge lists in a specific order python

Tags: python, list

How can I merge these 3 lists in this specific way?

Input:

```
l1 = [0, 0]
l2 = [1, 1, 1]
l3 = [2, 2, 2]
```

Output:

```
merged = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your lists don’t contain `None`s, [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) will produce these tuples:

```
>>> for t in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3):
...     print(t)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2)
(None, 1, 2)
```

which you can then [chain together](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and filter the `None`s out of:

```
merged = [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3))
          if x is not None]
```

Or shorter, since there’s already a list comprehension:

```
merged = [x for t in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3) for x in t
          if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from functools import partial 
from operator import is_not   
import itertools
list(filter(partial(is_not, None), itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(l1,l2,l3))))                                                                                 

# [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```